# Rotate the result of a loop around an object

Tags: animation-nodes

After getting involved into animation nodes, I achieved creating a simple array. It evenly distributes instances of an object on a circle.

What i want to achieve in a next step is rotating this array around an object, say an empty in the center. How can i do this. I tried, but i can only rotate around the instances around their individual origin.

[image: My circle array]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the Transform Vector node like so:

[image]

Keep in mind that we are only changing the location of the object, so they won't rotate or scale. You could do that too, but it works a bit differently:

[image]

Side note: You can think of a matrix as a container for the location, rotation and scale of an object. Combining multiple matrices means to execute these transformations one after the other. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWkK11PQG_Y) is small video I made to explain the basics of matrices for artists. Maybe it helps to understand this node tree better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see I have to learn a lot to understand animation nodes and to use it properly.